# Snowflake Materialized View Not Updating

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have materialized views in Snowflake that is not refreshing.  Below is a basic example of what I'm doing.

```
--Create table and insert two records
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1 (ID INTEGER);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2);

--Create materialized view on table
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW VW_T1 AS SELECT ID AS AVG_ID FROM T1;

--Insert two more records after creating the materialized view
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (4);

-- Show metadata
SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS LIKE '%T1';
```

No matter how long I wait, the view does not seem to be updating. The row count is always 2.  Behind_by always has a value.

What am i doing wrong.  I have followed the troubleshooting in the Snowflake documentation, but no success. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html#troubleshooting

Marius

Comment: fyi very question meta, you can insert many rows via `INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1),(2);`

Comment: but having run your example, and do a `select * from VW_T1;` after the `show` and getting the expected rows, and doing the `show...` again and getting the old rows I agree to get the same values back.. and swapped to a different warehouse and ran the select and shows again, still correct results from select, but old result from show

Comment: sounds like a bug to me, and I would open a ticket with support.

Comment: i can see 4 records at my end. Could you please check column `refreshed_on` on `SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS` , what time it is showing.

Comment: @PIG he is noting the results of the `show` command have the wrong count of rows, not that the view itself has those rows.

Comment: If you check the query profile, does the second Show query pull from cache?

Comment: Everything works as expected, I was just too impatient.  I expected the view to be updated within a a few minutes to an hour max.  In my case it took longer than that. But eventually, it did update the view.  Eventually, records started showing up in SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.MATERIALIZED_VIEW_REFRESH_HISTORY());  I can't find any information that tells me how often materialized view will be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Snowflake materialized views are different than materliazed views on other databases. Two important points:

1) Materialized views are automatically and transparently maintained by Snowflake.

2) Materialized views **provide always current data**. If a query is run before the materialized view is up-to-date, Snowflake either updates the materialized view or uses the up-to-date portions of the materialized view and retrieves any required newer data from the base table.

So you do not need to worry about the updates. It will be updated in the background time to time (based on some criteria such as DML size, DML count, time). You can see when it's updated if you check the "refreshed_on" column on the output of SHOW command.

---------- Extra info --------------

MV keeps the data on its own data files. The SHOW command shows "when the data is refreshed", "how many rows it contains" etc... Marius saw 2 rows, because the MV had 2 rows at that point. When Marius add more rows to the source table, MV will not copy them immediately. There are some thresholds, but if you try to read from MV, MV will read the delta from source table, and provide current data all the time. The users do not need to worry about the "behind_by", "refreshed_on" or "number of rows" (unless the lag is several days).

In summary, SHOW command and MV seem working as expected.

Comment: my reading of his question is, "the materialized view works, but the show command details are wrong" which means if you are using the show command output for "something" in of itself those results cannot be used. And I re-looked at my/his views, and they where up to-date just now, but after inserting more rows, and fetching those rows from the view, the `rows` count and `up-to-date` and `refreshed-on` where all wrong. so your point is as incorrect as the point he is trying to make.

Comment: I understood the situation, and I added more details to my answer to explain.

Comment: Ah this extra explanation makes more sense, to the gap in what was seen in the show and the behavior from the select.

Comment: @GokhanAtil how does it work if the MV is created over a external table. How does it know which files to be read from the external table, if the MV is not refreshed when new files are added to the external table