# Materialized views showing zero rows in show syntax

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have built materialized view on external table that have some billion rows. When i run command
`show materialized views`  it is showing `0` in `rows` columns.

When i run the select query with limit on "MV" it returns some rows `select * from MV_TABLE limit 3`
But If i run simple command of `select count(*)` it is running unending.   How can i know whether materilized views holds data or it is giving result from external table on fly. ?

Comment: you might find this other MV question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200534/snowflake-materialized-view-not-updating/61202209#61202209

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has been stated here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Why-is-the-row-count-reported-by-SHOW-MATERIALIZED-VIEWS-command-not-updated-when-I-insert-new-rows-to-the-source-table

Reason according to the above link is that the results of `SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS` are based on the data files of the materialized view and changes to the base table are not immediately merged there. This could be the reason for the discrepancy.

If you try to run `SHOW MATERIALIZED VIEWS` in a few minutes again, the question is, whether it is still returning 0 rows.

Comment: after long hour of waiting , it is still showing zero records only.